# How to update the content of view pager once it is initialized?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, google-cloud-messaging, android-sqlite

I have a `view pager` in the `MainActivity`, this `view pager` contains two tabs 
`RecentFeed` and `SavedFeed` both uses the same `FeedFragment` as both has same layout

Now I want to update the contents of these fragments when a new `gcm message` is
recieved or there occurs a change in my database

here is what  have done so far :

I created a `changelistening` interface as follows-

```
public interface OnDatabaseChangeListener {

void onChange();
}
```

Then used this in `helper` class to notify changes as follows

```
private OnDatabaseChangeListener databaseChangeListener;
public void setDatabaseChangeListener(OnDatabaseChangeListener databaseChangeListener){
    this.databaseChangeListener = databaseChangeListener;
}


public void addNewAlertToDB(Alert alert) {
        .
        .     
    databaseChangeListener.onChange();
    Log.d(TAG, "Added new alert " + title);
}
```

then Inside my GCMListenerService I do this

```
            DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this).addNewAlertToDB(alert);
            DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this)
                    .setDatabaseChangeListener(new OnDatabaseChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChange() {
                       //what should I do here to update viewpager content in MAinActivity
                }
            });
```

Similarly inside My `RecentFeed` tab I click a feed to save ...so that it is moved to `SavedFeed` tab...

```
void onSaveClicked(View view, int pos) {
    DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context)
            .saveAlert(alerts.get(pos));
    DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context)
            .setDatabaseChangeListener(new OnDatabaseChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChange() {
                     //what should I do here to update viewpager content in MAinActivity
                }
            });
    removeItem(pos);
    addItem(0);
    Snackbar.make(view, "Item Saved", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("UNDO", null).show();
    view.setEnabled(false);
}
```

But to my surprise `SavedFeed` is still empty.... Now If I close the app and restart ...the `savedfeed` tab is having content.
So I figured that content is being saved but not update on `viewpager` adapter of saved feed.

So what I want to know is how to update content instantly in `RecentFeed` when it recieves a gcm-message and how to update `savefeed` when a feed is saved from `recentfeed`.

Comment: post your full code, so that i can assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are doing the following in your feed listview's adapter:

```
 adapter.notifydatasetchanged()
```

As for viewpager you can do this just in case (though the default is 1 or 2):

```
 viewpager.setOffscreenpagelimit
```

Besides of all, make sure that these functions are executed on the UI thread.

Comment: This helped in saving the content to saved feed....but how to deal with a new gcm message case for Recent feeds

Comment: no setOffscreenpagelimit did not help because I have only two pages

Comment: In your broadcast receiver you need to have listeners that will subscribe and then call listeners on messageReceive... Don't forget to do it in UI thread, it is crucial. And on page clicked or switched, still do  adapter.notifydatasetchanged()