# How to update a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have Messanger App that has a Master/Detail Flow Layout with 2 fragments. I used the template provided by Android Studio.
When the ListFragment is in the foreground and a new user logs in the ListView is not immediately updated and the User does not appear on the List.
When I select a different activity and go back to the ListFragment afterwards the list is updated.

this is where my data is stored. If a new user logs in the addUser method is called and this adds the user to the List and Map.

```
public static List<ChatContent> ITEMS = new ArrayList<ChatContent>();

public static Map<String, ChatContent> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, ChatContent>();

protected static void addUser(ChatContent userChatContent) {
    ITEMS.add(userChatContent);
    ITEM_MAP.put(userChatContent.user, userChatContent);
}
```

This is how I set the listAdapter in the onCreate method of the ListFragment.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ChatData.ChatContent>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            ChatData.ITEMS);

    setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

FYI: The same thing happens when I'm on the detailsFragment and a new chat message arrives: the message does not appear unless I leave the activity and come back.

Comment: I m facing the same problem too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996883/how-to-update-the-content-of-view-pager-once-it-is-initialized/32998458

Comment: post your full code, so that i can assist you buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your data ,you should use these code to update the UI.

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I guess the problem I am facing now is that I dont know how to acces to the fragment.

Comment: Use handler to access the fragment.

Comment: Use LocalBroadcastManager!